# mostrar resultado de consulta Spring java en la vista

Tags: java, spring-mvc

**Vista:**

```
<body>
    <p>Hola bienvenido</p>
    <c:forEach items="${datos}" var="dato">
        <c:out value="${dato.ID}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</body>
```

**Conector:**  (funciona la conección)

```
public DriverManagerDataSource conectar(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dm=new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dm.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dm.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/gameunity");
    dm.setUsername("root");
    dm.setPassword("");
    return dm;
}
```

**Controlador:**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    private JdbcTemplate template;

    public MainController(){
        Conector con=new Conector();
        this.template=new JdbcTemplate(con.conectar());   
    }

    @RequestMapping("index.htm")
    public ModelAndView index(){
        ModelAndView res=new ModelAndView();
        String consulta="select * from cliente";
        List datos    =this.template.queryForList(consulta);
        res.addObject("datos", datos);
        res.setViewName("index");
        return res;
    }
}
```

No logro que muestre datos de mi base de datos en mi vista, cual es mi error?

---

He simplificado el código a fin de pasar un atributo simple desde el controlador, pero sigo sin poder mostrarlo en la vista.

**Vista:**

```
<body>
    <p>Hola bienvenido</p>
        <c:out value="${datos}"/>
</body>
```

**Controlador:**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {


    @RequestMapping("index.htm")
    public ModelAndView index(){
        ModelAndView res=new ModelAndView();
//        String consulta="select * from cliente";
//        List datos    =this.template.queryForList(consulta);
//        ArrayList<String> paraEnviar=new ArrayList();
        String dato="hola";
        res.addObject("dato",dato);
        res.setViewName("index");
        return res;
    }       
}
```

No logro que muestre el valor de la variable `datoAux` en la vista, ¿cuál es mi error?
edit: aumentando informacion:

> dispachet-servet

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">MainController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="MainController"
          class="controller.MainController"/>
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

> web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: `@RequestMapping("index.htm")` no deberia ser con extension `html`?

Comment: @AlbertoRojas es indistinto. Al colocar eso, significa que el servidor va a responder cuando se haga request a `http://<tu_servidor>:<puerto>/<nombre_app>/index.htm`.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que el código actual en la pregunta tiene problemas? ¿Cómo es que lo estás probando? Necesitamos más información de tu proyecto, como la estructura de los archivos, la ubicación de tu archivo de vista y las configuraciones que tienes para ello.

Answer (score 3):

Una de las cosas que haria seria crear un objeto Cliente, que reciba los datos de la consulta, y guardaria todos los clientes en un `ArrayList`de clientes. una vez hecho esto, lo pasas a la Request, y accedes a el desde el `archivo.jsp`, y en la repetitiva buscas cada objeto de Cliente, y de ahi sacas el dato necesario para mostrar

Comment: edite mi pregunta, lo simplifique ahora es mostrar el valor de una variable creado estaticamente

Answer (score 2):

La función queryForList devuelve un Objeto de tipo List con una colección de Maps que se corresponden a cada una de las filas de la tabla.

Cuando tuve que iterar por listas de Maps la notación que indicas no sirve, prueba con lo siguiente:

```
<c:forEach items="${datos}" var="dato" varStatus="status">
      <li>${dato["ID"]}</li>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: @larwain edite mi pregunta, lo simplifique ahora es mostrar el valor de una variable creado estaticamente

Comment: @hubman he probado el código que adjuntas en uno de mis proyectos y me funciona perfectamente. Yo haría las siguientes comprobaciones: comprobar en el fichero web.xml la versión del Servlet API, debe ser 2.4 o superior (yo tengo la 3.0) y verificar que en tu página JSP estás incluyendo las taglibs: '<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>'

Comment: @larwain tengo <load-on-startup>2.4</load-on-startup>, te refieres a eso ?

Comment: @hubman en el fichero web.xml la primera directiva es el tag <web-app> comprueba que ese tag la propiedad "version" sea al menos 2.4 o superior. Por ejemplo ´<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   id="MyAppID" version="3.0">´

Comment: @larwain esta asi: <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

Comment: @larwain un favor nos podemos poner en contacto para que me pases tu codigo que funciona porfavor?

Comment: Disculpa estuve de vacaciones y no había visto tu comentario. Si aún necesitas ayuda puedes ponerte en contacto conmigo.

Comment: @larwain si aun necesito tu ayuda, mi correo es devaiza123@gmail.com gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar armar una List con el Objeto "dato" cargados a mano, para dividir el problema.

Por otro lado te recomiendo que use en la vista el formato "dato.id" en minúscula, dado que generalmente los framework al intentar resolver la propiedad id, van a ír a buscar el setter y getter de dicha propiedad, es decir que en la clase deberías tener setId() and getId().

Comment: edite mi pregunta, lo simplifique ahora es mostrar el valor de una variable creado estaticamente

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ver este tutorial en donde se explica una aplicación similar, el error puede estar en el controlador, la configuración del Servlet, el HandlerMapping o el ViewResolver, pero, sin la aplicación completa no es fácil saberlo por lo que te recomiendo el siguiente tutorial: http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2017/03/spring-mvc-vistas-jsp.html